# Information from drop down fields not going to email

Tags: jquery

I have request quote form with multiple fields. After filling them all down and hitting send message button. The information from all fields go to my email correctly except drop down input fields. Can you please help me to fix this.
This is an example of 2 fields out of form

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 well">
  <form name="quoteForm" id="quoteForm" novalidate>       
    <div class="col-xs-6 control-group form-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <label>Trailer Type:</label>
        <select name="trailer" class="form-control" id="trailer" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter trailer type.">
          <option value="Dry Van">Dry Van</option>
          <option value="Flatbed">Flatbed</option>
          <option value="Step Deck">Step Deck</option>
          <option value="Double Drop">Double Drop</option>
          <option value="Temp Control">Temp Control</option>
        </select>
        <p class="help-block"></p>
      </div>
    </div>        
    <div class="col-xs-12 control-group form-group">
      <label>Dimentions Per Unit:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 control-group form-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <label>Length:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="length" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter length.">
        <p class="help-block"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 control-group form-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <label>Width:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="width" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter width.">
        <p class="help-block"></p>
      </div>
    </div>        
    <!-- For success/fail messages -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Risa, please provide the code you use to access the form fields. The error will most certainly not be in the markup

Comment: How can I add my js code in here?

Comment: just add a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/98kv2y7q/

Comment: @Risa your this question is also very much unclear like last one, what you mean to 2 input fields out of the form, on one hand you are saying dropdown values not sent in email on other hand an example code where 2 fields out of the form but in example code and in fiddle there are no fields out of the form and in fiddle please remove irrelevant  code and read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put the `name` attribute for the 2 `input` fields.

Comment: Hi, Can somebody help with this issue please.Still cannot find the bug.

Comment: I mean the name for the input field.  
<input `name="length"`>

Comment: Also, may I know which fields were you having the issue? The "trailer type", "length" or "width"?

Comment: Hi bankiat, I have <input id="length" Problem with drop down fields. Like when I select one of the state. Or "trailer type" as an example.

Comment: If field is <input type="text" or "number"> it works

Comment: If field <select name="trailer" class="form-control" id="loadtype"> it doesn't

Comment: in your jQuery, change `$("input#trailer").val();` to `$("#trailer").val();`